# How to handle cases in which the generated content depends on the current user authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, implementation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and, since my system implementation, I would like to generate different outputs (in views) and / or to retrieve different records (in controllers) depending on the "access-*er*" user authorization (for instance, the authorization could depend on if the "access-*ed*" user *is* or *not* is the current "access-*er*" user).

How can I handle the situation? That is, for example in order to handle if the user is or not the current user and so to display different content, should I implement two view files and / or controller actions for each case, or should I use `if else` statements directly in the view file and / or in the controller action?

Comment: wat? is or not your question hard to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner approach I would suggest is to create different roles for users and group them. So for that particular group you can have a separate view files and controllers. One advantage  of this approach is it will be very easy to read the code and we can easily understand the code. We get more control on the page easily without having to worry about other users. We can     even avoid the need for many filters. But if there is only two type of users then it could be managed easily with if else statement, so choosing the right method will depends on the problem too.

Comment: What do you mean with "different roles for users and group them"? That is, how you'd to group users? What "kind" / "type" of roles do you are referring to?

Comment: there can be different kind of users like admins, data entry users, normal users that depends on the application so to distinguish them you can assign them some sort of role.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use if else statements right in the views, and render partials if there is a lot of markup between the statements to keep things clean.

That is a style choice though so if you are finding you are making massive conditionals on every page, it could be that you need to rethink your organization in the controller or even make a new resource. For simple things like adding an 'edit' or 'delete' button if the user is an admin, I would use conditionals in the view.

For .html.erb markup, you can do normal if/else blocks like this:

```
<% if <condition> %>
  <%= render 'partial_name' %>
<% else %>
  <p>Some other content</p>
<% end %>
```

Where condition is your condition, like for example `current_user? @user`

Comment: You said *"[...] it could be that you need to [...] make a new resource"*. How can I "become aware" / "be sure" of having to implement a *new resource*? That is, how you'd solve my issue by implementing a *new resource*?

Comment: Well again there are a million ways to make any website, but you want the cleanest and clearest. So if you had for instance a School model that had all sorts of different behavior for colleges and middle schools, maybe it would be better to separate them into a MiddleSchool model and College model with some kind of abstract School module or superclass.